# Store cv::Mat instance on Heap in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers

This is not a only OpenCV related but also a general C++ question.

I want to load an image inside a method and store it on the heap using a pointer.

Here is the code for the method I'm currently using:

```
int load_offline_image(std::string src, unsigned char* buffer, int* width, int* height, int* len) {
    if (offline_image) {
        delete offline_image;
    }
    offline_image = new cv::Mat(cv::imread(src, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE));
    if (offline_image->data == 0){
        return ERROR;
    }
    int numRow = offline_image->rows;
    int numCol = offline_image->cols;
    *len = numCol*numRow*offline_image->elemSize1();
    *width = offline_image->size().width;
    *height = offline_image->size().height;
    buffer = offline_image->data;
    return OK;
}
```

Everything works fine inside the method. But when I try to access the `buffer` variable from outside, it's `Null`. I'm sure the issue is related to the fact the pointer `offline_image` is pointing to a `cv::Mat` instance which just exists on the Stack and that it's address is lost after the execution of `load_offline_image` has finished.

BTW: `offline_image` is a global variable.

What's the proper way to implement this in C++, so that I allocate Heap space for the `cv::Mat` instance?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, this seems wrong. If you better explain what's your goal, we can probably find a better way to achieve that

Comment: Well, I want to create a dll that can load images from a file system and to perform some processing. Since the calling application does not have access to third parties like opencv, it's necessary to retrieve the image as uchar* with width, height and length. So my goal is it to return all this data by that method. It's also important that only one images is loaded at a time. So I added the line which deletes the pointer whenever another images is loaded. Is that enough information?

Comment: Yep. I cannot answer, now... but basically allocate the buffer with `new`, and use `memcpy` to copy the `offline_image->data` into the `buffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is something like this:

```
int load_offline_image(std::string src, unsigned char** buffer, int* width, int* height, int* len) {
    ...
    *buffer = offline_image->data;
    ....
}
```

This reason for this is - you want to change the address pointed to by `buffer`. Using `unsigned char* buffer` changes the address but the change is limited only to the calling method. You need an `unsigned char**` for the change to persist beyond the method.

Also, I would recommend you consider the stride width - which might be different from the image width. You can query `offline_image.isContinuous()` to figure this out.

On another note, this is not an appropriate way to use `cv::Mat`. Also, it's not clear who's *responsibility* it would be to clear out memory pointed to by `buffer`. Here is a cleaner approach:

```
int main() {
    // Calling application
    buffer = new unsigned char[width*height*dims];
    ...
    load_offline_image(..., buffer, width, height, ...);
    ...
    delete[] buffer;
}

int load_offline_image(...) {
    Mat offline_image;
    // use imread
    // Copy the buffer over
    memcpy(buffer, offline_image->data, ...);
    // Since we're using the Mat structure, the Mat will be deallocated automatically
}
```

This decouples the two functions and lets them manage their memory separately.